# Ip Log file_get_content()

Tags: php, logging, ip, file-get-contents

I'm using the function `file_get_contents("www.example.com");`. 
Now i want to know if the website `www.example.com` see the user ip or the serverip from the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP runs on the server, not the client, the website sees the server IP.